# Android Local Peers

Tags: android, bluetooth, p2p

I'm attempting to work on a multiplayer game for android
and would like to have local multiplayer capability.  Aka people playing in the same room, coffee house, etc (aka peer to peer)

The trick is I do not want to have to require the players have to actually 
find each other to have their phones connect and exchange the game moves.

I've looked at Bluetooth (and worked with the bluetooth chat demo app) 
and the problem is the pairing system pretty much assumes you can check the other device's pin.

Are their any other suggestions people have gotten to work? Or am I missing
something about how bluetooth operates and you can do the equivalent of a local adhoc network?

I know I'm considering:
1 - GPS to figure out where the player is and let the game server handle the communications via wifi.
2 - Use the bluetooth discovery system and MAC address to let the clients see who is local and then let the game server take it from their.

Thanks

Comment: Why not an Announce system using broadcast or even multicast? You walk into a room or a coffee house and find who is online...

Comment: Will this work even if player A is still on the cellular internet and player B is on the local area routed network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord() and createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() APIs ? they are available from API level 10 ,

These uses the new pairing method called SSP and does not require user to enter a pin to pair.

Comment: Nice but have to currently build for Android 2.2 as is is the dominant versions on the market.

Answer (score 0):

If by local you mean LAN, then use communication on a pre-agreed multicast ip address. It will be much simpler.

Comment: Can't assume they are on the same LAN.  Player A may be on a wi-fi signal but player B may be on the coffee house's local routed network.